# Github pages can't be included in a Shiny app?

Tags: github, iframe, shiny

anyone know have to display a github pages webpage in a shiny app?

I have tried several previous solutions, but they did not work. 
I tried to use local html fiels, and includeHTML(html_file). But I used d3 in my html file, thus I have to upload these html files to a server first. 
My second try is tag$iframe. I updated the html files to github pages, and they works well if I visit the link directly. But when I include the link in a shiny app using tag$iframe, the page was simply blank. 
Below is the code for the tag$iframe option (which does not work).

```
output$gbaPlot1 <- renderUI({
tags$iframe(seamless="seamless", 
src='http://conxz.net/', width='100%')
})
```

I expected github pages would show within the shiny app. But it was just blank.